# Zsh autocompletion breaks when I add a wrapper to a command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zsh

For example I have a test `app` executable

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
  (foo)
    echo "selected foo"
    ;;
  (bar)
    echo "selected bar"
    ;;
esac
```

And a simple completion for it included in fpath

```
#compdef app
local -a subcmds
subcmds=('foo:show foo' 'bar:show bar')
_describe 'app' subcmds
```

It works fine. Now I want to make a wrapper that adds a subcommand to the app

```
__app_wrapper () {
    if [[ "$1" == baz ]]; then
        echo "selected baz"
    else
        command app "$@"
    fi
}

alias app=__app_wrapper
```

Once I `source` it, subcommand works fine, but autocompletion switches to completing with files in current dir instead of what my completion script provides. Why is that and how to fix it? Is it because app is now function instead of executable?

I'm actually trying to use a way more complicated completion script for `docker-machine` but I was able to reduce my problem to this example.

Comment: I have a very similar problem (with a proxy wrapper for `docker`). Have you figured out any way to fix this?

Comment: @JakubArnold added an answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `compdef`, here what I ended up with (for my real case):

```
#
# Function wrapper to docker-machine that adds a use subcommand.
#
# The use subcommand runs `eval "$(docker-machine env [args])"`, which is a lot
# less typing.
#
# To enable:
#  1a. Copy this file somewhere and source it in your .bashrc
#      source /some/where/docker-machine-wrapper.bash
#  1b. Alternatively, just copy this file into into /etc/bash_completion.d
#
# Configuration:
#
# DOCKER_MACHINE_WRAPPED
#   When set to a value other than true, this will disable the alias wrapper
#   alias for docker-machine. This is useful if you don't want the wrapper,
#   but it is installed by default by your installation.
#

: ${DOCKER_MACHINE_WRAPPED:=true}

__docker_machine_wrapper () {
    if [[ "$1" == use ]]; then
        # Special use wrapper
        shift 1
        case "$1" in
            -h|--help|"")
                cat <<EOF
Usage: docker-machine use [OPTIONS] [arg...]
Evaluate the commands to set up the environment for the Docker client
Description:
   Argument is a machine name.
Options:
   --swarm  Display the Swarm config instead of the Docker daemon
   --unset, -u  Unset variables instead of setting them
EOF
                ;;
            *)
                eval "$(docker-machine env "$@")"
                echo "Active machine: ${DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME}"
                ;;
        esac
    elif [[ "$1" == "--help" || "$1" == "-h" ]]; then
    command docker-machine "$@"
        echo "  use         Get the URL of a machine"
    else
        # Just call the actual docker-machine app
        command docker-machine "$@"
    fi
}

if [[ ${DOCKER_MACHINE_WRAPPED} = true ]]; then
    alias docker-machine=__docker_machine_wrapper
    compdef __docker_machine_wrapper=docker-machine
fi
```

In addition I've edited the actual completion file to show machine names